# How do I correctly type Sequelize JOINs using TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to JOIN two tables together in Sequelize:

```
const results = await MainModel.findAll({ include: [ JoinedModel ] });
```

However, TypeScript (in `--strict` mode, at least) complains when I try to access data from the joined table:

```
const joinedField = results[0].joinedModel.joinedField;
```

which results in:

```
Property 'joinedModel' does not exist on type 'Instance<MainModelAttributes>'.
```

Despite TypeScript's complaint, the above code *does* actually provide me with the value in the joined field.

What is the correct way to type this? (And am I using Sequelize correctly here?)

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the result in this manner.

```
const results = await MainModel.findAll({ include: [ JoinedModel ] }) as Array<MainModel & {JoinedModel: JoinedModel}>;
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because the result of `findAll` is a Promise. Try this:

```
MainModel.findAll({ include: [ JoinedModel ] }).then(result => {
 your code here...
});
```

Comment: Oops, that was a mistake by me when trimming the code for this question. However, that's not the issue - the code actually works, it's just TypeScript that's complaining.

Comment: When handling the Promise's result, there should be no complains... In addition, you can explicitly cast the result to your desired type.

Comment: Well, there are... (I'll update the post to add that I'm using TypeScript's strict mode.) Explicit casting is of course possible, but I'd rather have the types be inferred correctly to avoid introducing errors myself.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this because sequelize function will return the results as model instance which contains sequelize metadatas, So from stringifying and parsing the response you can get JSON representation of the result.

```
let results = await MainModel.findAll({ include: [ JoinedModel ] });
results = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
const joinedField = results[0].joinedModel.joinedField;
```

**OR**

You can use the query option raw to get the response as a plain json.

```
let results = await MainModel.findAll({raw: true, include: [ JoinedModel ] });
```

Reference: [Sequelize Doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-toJSON)

Comment: Thanks @Imrahamed, but I don't need the JSON representation of the result - the code as I showed it already worked. What I need(ed) for it was for TypeScript to understand it, rather than it spewing out the error message I showed.

Comment: const results: any = await MainModel.findAll({ include: [ JoinedModel ] });
You can define type as any to prevent that error.

Comment: Yes, any is a way to bail out of typing, and that's what I did to work around this. However, I'd prefer to properly type it, which is what this question was about...